# Is the distribution package (.tgz) of Apache Kafka available as a Maven dependency?

Tags: maven, apache-kafka

I would like to add Apache Kafka .tgz archive contents to my Maven project's distribution package. I was not able to find the archive on Maven Central. Any reason why it is not there?

Answer (score 1):

Maven Central generally has jars and POMs, not tarballs.

[The `kafka` module](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka), (not kafka-clients) includes everything needed to programmatically [run a `KafkaServer` class](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/kafka-KafkaServer.html), though you'd want `KafkaServerStartable` to initialize that

Comment: Not really true. For example, another Apache project, Karaf, has the tarball available in Maven Central: https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.karaf%22%20AND%20a%3A%22apache-karaf%22

Comment: I am aware that I can do it programmatically, but say I want to use their scripts. I would have to either add the archive to my sources or put it on my internal Nexus repo. Would be easier to just have it in the central repo.

Comment: Well, there are different developers on each project, and Kafka doesn't do that... The tarballs are on Apache mirrors, so it's not clear why it should be on Maven

Comment: And I don't know what you mean "their scripts"... the bash startup scripts just run `java kafka.KafkaServer` basically